# $M-N$ Unbounded Sequence Proof

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Did I do this correctly? I want to prove the sequence does not converge.

$$a_n = \{\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\}$$

$$a_n = \{n+1\}$$

WTS: $\forall M>0, \exists N>0 | \forall n \in$ N, if $n>N$ then $a_n > M$

Proof:

Let $M>0$ be arbitrary, Chose $N=$________ $>0$

$$a_n = n+1
> n > N$$

(Go back and choose $N = M$)

$$N=M$$

as wanted

qed

Comment: Aye, that works.

Comment: perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you have written is actually how most people would prove this in their *heads*. But if you are looking for a valid mathematical proof, you have to go backwards. What I mean by going backwards is something like this:
Proof. Let $M \gt 0$ be arbitrary. Let $N = M$. Then for all $n \gt N$ we have:
$$a_n = n+1 \gt n \gt N = M.$$
Thus we have found the requisite $N$ for $M$. Since $M$ was arbitrary, this completes the proof. $\square$ 
Now in this version we don't have the ambiguity of what $N$ is in the first part of your the proof. I'll grant you this that most people (including myself) will think just like the way you think about this problem, but turning it to an actual mathematical proof needs a little bit of thinkering with the flow of it.

Comment: I would be putting that $N=M$ in the start but I just wanted to demonstrate my flow of reasoning, but I absolutely agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is correct. Without returning to the definition, you could also say that
$$
a_n = n+1 \rightarrow + \infty
$$
when $n \rightarrow + \infty$.

Comment: the question required me to prove it, I don't think that would fly with my prof on the exam XD

Comment: @Krio Well, if you have more a complicated sequence, returning to the definition is not always as easy.